# StringBuffer Append Space (" ") Appends "null" Instead

Tags: java, android

Basically what I'm trying to do is take a String, and replace each letter in the alphabet inside, but preserving any spaces and not converting them to a "null" string, which is the main reason I am opening this question.

If I use the function below and pass the string "a b", instead of getting "ALPHA BETA" I get "ALPHAnullBETA".

I've tried all possible ways of checking if the individual char that is currently iterated through is a space, but nothing seems to work. All these scenarios give false as if it's a regular character.

```
public String charConvert(String s) {

    Map<String, String> t = new HashMap<String, String>(); // Associative array
    t.put("a", "ALPHA");
    t.put("b", "BETA");
    t.put("c", "GAMA");
    // So on...

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(0);
    s = s.toLowerCase(); // This is my full string

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);

        String st = String.valueOf(c);
        if (st.compareTo(" ") == 1) {
            // This is the problematic condition
            // The script should just append a space in this case, but nothing seems to invoke this scenario
        } else {
            sb.append(st);
        }

    }

    s = sb.toString();

    return s;
}
```

Comment: compareTo returns 0 if objects are equal

Comment: Character.isWhitespace(c) is what you can use.

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`compareTo()` will return 0 if the strings are equal. It returns a positive number of the first string is "greater than" the second.

But really there's no need to be comparing Strings. You can do something like this instead:

```
char c = s.charAt(i);

if(c == ' ') {
    // do something
} else {
    sb.append(c);
}
```

Or even better for your use case:

```
String st = s.substring(i,i+1);
if(t.contains(st)) {
    sb.append(t.get(st));
} else {
    sb.append(st);
}
```

To get even cleaner code, your Map should from `Character` to `String` instead of `<String,String>`.

Answer (score 2):

`String.compareTo()` returns 0 if the strings are equal, not 1. Read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

Note that for this case you don't need to convert the char to a string, you could do

```
if(c == ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 Character.isWhitespace(c)
```

that solves the issue. Best practice.

Answer (score 0):

First, of all, what is `s` in this example? It's hard to follow the code. Then, your compareTo seems off:

```
if (st.compareTo(" ") == 1)
```

Should be

```
if (st.compareTo(" ") == 0)
```

since 0 means "equal" ([read up](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10) on compareTo)

Answer (score 0):

From the compareTo documentation: `The result is a negative integer if this String object lexicographically precedes the argument string. The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal;`

You have the wrong condition in `if (st.compareTo(" ") == 1) {`

Answer (score 0):

The compareTo method of a String returns -1 if the source string precedes the test string, 0 for equality, and 1 if the source string follows. Your code checks for 1, and it should be checking for 0.